# Why does the implementations of Map handle null differently?

Tags: java

Let's take the `containsKey(Object key)` as example:

- TreeMap throws a NullPointerException if the key is null.
- TreeMap returns false if there is no mapping for the key.
- HashMap doesn't throw a NullPointerException and never returns null.

Comment: ["This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: I learned, each object has being designed for a different usage and requirements. By the way: you forgot to add "HashMap returns false if there is no mapping for the key".

Comment: Also on [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html): "Some map implementations have restrictions on the keys and values they may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null keys and values, and some have restrictions on the types of their keys". Your question shows that you did not go into the documentation first.

Comment: “HashMap … never returns null.” That is true of all Map.containsKey implementations, because containsKey returns a boolean, which, like all primitives, cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Some map implementations have restrictions on the keys and values they
>   may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null keys and
>   values, and some have restrictions on the types of their keys.
>   Attempting to insert an ineligible key or value throws an unchecked
>   exception, typically NullPointerException or ClassCastException.
>   Attempting to query the presence of an ineligible key or value may
>   throw an exception, or it may simply return false; some
>   implementations will exhibit the former behavior and some will exhibit
>   the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Lets have a look into the Javadoc for TreeSet:

[*Throws NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null keys*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object))

Meaning: those two Map implementations really have **different** semantics. Therefore it makes sense that their individual implementations of "Map" methods do work differently.

One key property of TreeSet is the fact that it supports/requires *ordering*. That doesn't play nicely with *null*, thus it is "fair" to throw when *null* is coming in.